# Bootstrap 3 thumbnail spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have two rows of  100x100px thumbnails on  screens 700 and above with ideally 30px spacing on sides and bottom. The thumbnails are in a div that limits the width to 700px then fancybox opens them up larger. I would like the thumbnails to retain the same padding and just adjust to various screen sizes but changing the amount of rows.  Below is what I am using which is getting close but I am hoping there is a better way to fine tune this.

```
<div class="inner cover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
            <a data-fancybox-title="<p><em>this tittle/em>, smapletext.</p><p>  This is a whole bunch of text to use as a description</p>" class="fancybox" href="./placehold.it/700x00"><img src="./placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example with jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking to achieve, `float:left` is your buddy here...

CSS:

```
img{
  float:left; 
  margin:15px
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inner cover">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/700x700">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/700x700">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://placehold.it/700x700">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
    ...      
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/y6Q6lnJxdJ

You might also want to define a `max-width`, or put a `col-sm-8 col-sm-2-offset` in there get them into your specific sized box, or force your two rows, but it hopefully it gets you started.